# Generalized assignment

Tags: algorithm, glpk

I have a problem like this: there are Y people that need to be
assigned to no more than X sessions at different times according to
their availability, ensuring that no session contains more or less than a
given amount of people (Y/X +/- 20% for example).

The specific problem in which the number of people and the number of
sessions are the same seems to be the same as an assigmnent problem.

However, does anyone have an idea on how to solve this more genral
case?

I'm ok with both pseudo-algorithms or with suggestions on how to use
the GLPK. I could code this in perl or javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are referring to [Generalized assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_assignment_problem). which fits into your case. The generalized assignment problem is NP-hard